# How to use recruiter's message to get other job than he offered me?

Tags: job-search, hiring-process, recruitment, software-development, consulting

During my study of IT at a technical university, I worked almost a year as a Software Developer. I worked with Java, Spring and a little bit with React. After this experience, I do not want to work as S/W Developer anymore.

I was contacted by some recruiters at LinkedIn and they usually wanted to offer me dev job. I am not interested in that, but on the other hand, I guess I can use their interest to find a suitable job.

Personally, I prefer an administrative/consulting job, where I could use my knowledge of five languages and experience with customer support. I think I could be between devs and customers/managers, as I know both sides. However, in some companies, it is considered a senior job or as low-leveled Service Desk work.

What can I use their interest and make them find offers suitable for me?

Comment: You can of course respond with a description of what would fit you rather than simply declining their interest.  However first you will need to come up with a clear expression of what you want to do.  Even your post here does not make that clear - for example, when you say "knowledge of five languages" presumably you mean *spoken* languages, but in the context that could be very confusing.

Answer (score 7):

Just reach out to them and tell them that.  Nothing wrong with saying "I'm really not interested in that particular position, but would be interested in THIS type of job..." and then elaborate.

A recruiter will typically have a range of jobs available.    You may not be particularly suited for the one they sent you the info on, but I'm sure any recruiter would be thrilled to submit you for any other job you are interested in that they have.  THat's how they get paid.     Even if a recruiter HASN'T contacted you, reach out.    If you've got a connection, use it.    Most jobs are filled not by what you know, but who you know.

Comment: I agree with this. It's fair to add, most third party recruiters are incredibly hungry. They get paid when people get hired. If there's any chance they can place you, you'll get their attention. You might as well leverage that energy. So, don't hesitate to do what this answer suggests.

Comment: You should highlight the last sentence. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is completely normal and happens all the time. I have personally talked to recruiters who reached out to me regarding different opportunities. If they have something available for you and they feel you are a good fit, they will help you. Plus its their job!

You can always reply like this:

> I appreciate you reaching out me regarding the XXX position, and while it sounds like 
>       an exciting opportunity, I am currently interested ZZZ or YYY positions. If you have 
>       positions that may fit my interests, please let me know and I'd be happy to forward 
>       you my resume/CV.

Worst case scenario, they don't have anything for you or simply don't reply.

Good luck!!